# How to customize login process

Tags: plugin-development, login

I want to create a new way to Login.

What I got to do now:

1. Edit the user form, adding a new field that is saved in user_meta
2. Edit the Login form, adding a new input;
3. Build a (safe) query that selects the user_id in usermeta table;

What I still need:

1. Catch the post to login, run my query (3) and accept this as a valid user.

I could do this if I could overwrite the `wp_signon` function, but this is not possible.

Any other alternative?

Comment: There are no code. My attempts so far have worked. But now I do not know how I can override the function wp_signin

Comment: Do you mean `wp_signon`?

Comment: yes, wp_signon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function in `functions.php` of your current theme 
It will show an extra field on login form

```
###################Code starts here ###################
<?php

add_action('login_form', 'add_login_field');
function add_login_field()
{
?>    
  <p>
      <label for="user_pass">My Input<br>
      <input type="text" name="my_name" value=""/>
  </p>
<?php  
}

function do_anything($user) {
    //do stuff

   $userdata= $user = get_userdatabylogin($user);
   $user_id = $userdata->ID;

   $my_name = $_POST['my_name'];



   add_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_name', $my_name);

}

add_action('wp_login', 'do_anything');
?>
############## CODE ENDS HERE ###################
```

The above code will create an extra field on the login form .
This value will be posted with other values that can be received in "`do_anything($user)`" function.  Finally this value can be saved as User meta.

**Part 2=======================================================================**

```
add_action('login_form', 'add_login_field');
function add_login_field()
{

?>    
       <p>
  <label for="user_pass">My Input<br>
  <input type="text" name="my_name" value=""/>
 </p>


 <?     
    }

function do_anything($user) {

    //do stuff

   $userdata= $user = get_userdatabylogin($user);
   $user_id = $userdata->ID;

   $my_name = $_POST['my_name'];


add_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_name', $my_name);
}
add_action('wp_login', 'do_anything');


add_filter('authenticate', 'check_login', 10, 3);

function check_login($user, $username, $password) {
  global $wpdb;  
if(isset($_POST['my_name']) && trim($_POST['my_name'])!="")
{
    $customfield    =   $_POST['my_name'];
$UsermetaData = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *FROM  wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value='$customfield'");
$user = get_user_by('id', $UsermetaData[0]->user_id );

// Redirect URL //

if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) )
{
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );
    wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );

    $redirect_to = user_admin_url();
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
    exit();
}
return $user;
}

}
```

**Please check this code snippet. Also you need to modify the code as per requirements. Make sure "my_name" field remain unique and it will not be updated every time on log in.**

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in item 2, I managed to do this. How can I do to create a WP session knowing only the field "my_name" (user name and password became optional)

Comment: Whenever we add any user meta then it always need a user id and the key for that data to save in the database.
The above functions will work only when we enter a valid username and password.

Now the functionality you want "my_name" value need to be unique w.r.t. which we will get to know which user id need to login.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Welcome @Falci. Thanks for adding the reference in your code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the input before the login completes, I would think you might just hook the [wp_authenticate action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate) and run your script there.

"This action is located inside of wp_signon. In contrast to the wp_login action, it is executed before the WordPress authentication process."